# ArrayIndexOutOfBound error when i used enhanced for loop

Tags: java, arrays, foreach, equals, arrayindexoutofboundsexception

Can we use enhanced for loop without getting ArrayIndexOutOfBound error.
because after using normal for loop it is working.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[] = {1,2,3,4};
        int b[] = {1,2,3,4};
 boolean status = true;
        if (a.length == b.length){
            for (int i:a){
                if (a[i] != b[i]){
                    status =false;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            status = false;
        }

        if (status == true){
            System.out.println("arrays are equal...");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("arrays not equal...");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could of course use `Arrays.equals`.

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173)

Comment: You have a wrong understanding of the usage of ```for (int i:a)```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are accessing the elements of array `a`.

The loop

```
for (int i : a) {
  System.out.println(i);
}
```

will print out the values: 1, 2, 3, 4.

You probably expected to get 0, 1, 2, 3 but that is not how the enhanced loop work.

### Improvement

Instead of comparing the two array by hand, you can use the convenience method `Arrays.equals()`:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a[] = {1,2,3,4};
    int b[] = {1,2,3,4};
    boolean status = java.util.Arrays.equals(a, b);

    if (status){
        System.out.println("arrays are equal...");
    } else {
        System.out.println("arrays not equal...");
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should suggest how to actually compare arrays manually, too. People in the LEARNING phase should FIRST code the solution themselves, and then you tell them: and in the real world, use this library call.

Comment: if (a.length == b.length){
            for (int i:a){
                if (a[i-1] != b[i-1]){
                    status =false;

                }
            }
        }
        now it is working

Comment: @Prajakta Yadav, this is only working because your array has these values: 1,2,3,4. Try with arrays like `{1,2,3,5}` or `{1,2,4}` and it won't work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

for (int i:a) // you mistake here, i equal to 1,2,3,4
array index must start 0

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[] = {1,2,3,4};
        int b[] = {1,2,3,4};
 boolean status = true;
        if (a.length == b.length){
            for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++){  // look at here 
                if (a[i] != b[i]){
                    status =false;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            status = false;
        }

        if (status == true){
            System.out.println("arrays are equal...");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("arrays not equal...");
        }
    }
}
```